# How to handle enumerations without enum fields in a database?

Tags: database-design, enums

How would I implement a enumeration field in a database that doesn't support enumerations? (i.e. SQLite)

The fields need to be easily searchable with "`field` = ?" so using any type of data serialization is a bad idea.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, please be nice. I did look for the answer on StackOverflow before I asked.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Using a foreign key to a **lookup table** is the approach I use.  In fact, I use this even when I do use a database that supports ENUM (e.g. MySQL).

For simplicity, I may skip the ever-present "`id`" for the lookup table, and just use the actual value I need in my main table as the primary key of the lookup table.  That way you don't need to do a join to get the value.

```
CREATE TABLE BugStatus (
  status            VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO BugStatus (status) VALUES ('NEW'), ('OPEN'), ('FIXED');

CREATE TABLE Bugs (
  bug_id            SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  summary           VARCHAR(80),
  ...
  status            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NEW',
  FOREIGN KEY (status) REFERENCES BugStatus(status)
);
```

Admittedly, storing strings takes more space than MySQL's implementation of `ENUM`, but unless the table in question has millions of rows, it hardly matters.

Other advantages of the lookup table are that you can add or remove a value from the list with a simple `INSERT` or `DELETE`, whereas with `ENUM` you have to use `ALTER TABLE` to redefine the list.

Also try querying the current list of permitted values in an `ENUM`, for instance to populate a pick-list in your user interface.  It's a major annoyance!  With a lookup table, it's easy: `SELECT status from BugStatus`.

Also you can add other attribute columns to the lookup table if you need to (e.g. to mark choices available only to administrators).  In an `ENUM`, you can't annotate the entries; they're just simple values.

Another option besides a lookup table would be to use **`CHECK` constraints** (provided the database supports them -- MySQL doesn't support CHECK until version 8.0.16):

```
CREATE TABLE Bugs (
  bug_id            SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  summary           VARCHAR(80),
  ...
  status            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    CHECK (status IN ('NEW', 'OPEN', 'FIXED'))
);
```

But this use of a `CHECK` constraint suffers from the same disadvantages as the `ENUM`:  hard to change the list of values without `ALTER TABLE`, hard to query the list of permitted values, hard to annotate values.

PS: the equality comparison operator in SQL is a single `=`.  The double `==` has no meaning in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the = vs. == thing :) It's been awhile since I've used SQL directly.

Comment: A bit old question, but awesome answer. Vote up.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that this Only works in MySQL if you are willing/interested in going with INNODB instead of MyISAM.

Comment: @mOrloff: Right, the foreign key constraint is supported in InnoDB but not MyISAM.  It is definitely best practice to use InnoDB instead of MyISAM for many reasons, this is just one.

Comment: best answer, 10 years later, +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

To restrict the possible values I would use a foreign key to a table that holds the enumeration items.

If you don't want to JOIN to do your searches then make the key a varchar if JOINS are not a problem then make the key an INT and don't join unless you need to search on that field.

Note that putting your enumerations in the DB precludes compile time checking of the values in your code (unless you duplicate the enumeration in code.)  I have found this to be a large down side.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options :

- use an integer field
- use a varchar field

I would personally advocate the use of varchars, because you won't break anything if you change your enum + the fields are human-readable, but ints have some pro aswell, namely performance (the size of the data is an obvious example)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did recently

In my hibernate mapped POJO- I kept the type of the member as String and it is VARCHAR in the database.

The setter for this takes an enum
There is another setter which takes String- but this is private (or you can map the field directly- if that's what you prefer.)

Now the fact I am using String is encapsulated from all. For the rest of the application- my domain objects use enum.
And as far as the database is concerned- I am using String.

If I missed your question- I apologize.

Comment: This makes sense. Ruby on Rails would allow the same behavior with validations as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring JPA 2.1 or later with hibernate you can implement your own AttributeConverter and define how your enum maps to column values

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class CategoryConverter implements AttributeConverter<Category, String> {
 
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Category category) {
        if (category == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return category.getCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Category convertToEntityAttribute(String code) {
        if (code == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return Stream.of(Category.values())
          .filter(c -> c.getCode().equals(code))
          .findFirst()
          .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

Please see the 4th solution in the article at [Persisting Enums in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa).The code snippet is also from there.

Answer (score -2):

I would use a varchar. Is this not an option for you?

Comment: Using a VARCHAR would lead to denormalized data. If you want to change the name of the enum value, it requires an update on the whole table, rather than just changing a single row in a reference table.