# MySQL Enum performance advantage?

Tags: mysql, enums

Is there a performance advantage to using enum in situations where there are only 5-10 different possible values for a field? if not what is the advantage?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There is a huge performance *penalty* to using `ENUM` for operations such as:

- Query the list of permitted values in the `ENUM`, for instance to populate a drop-down menu.  You have to query the data type from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and parse the list out of a BLOB field returned.
- Alter the set of permitted values.  It requires an `ALTER TABLE` statement, which locks the table and may do a restructure.

I'm not a fan of MySQL's `ENUM`.  I prefer to use lookup tables.  See also my answer to "[How to handle enumerations without enum fields in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761211/how-to-handle-enumerations-without-enum-fields-in-a-database/761343#761343)"

Comment: my enum values would be things like demographics (W,B,A,H,O,U) Gender(M,F,U) and Party(R,D,I,U) those would never change. so they can always be hard coded into my application logic. So Querying for dropdown values, and altering the structure are not that big of a factor.

Comment: "my enum values ... would never change". Would **love** to get some stats on how many times that statement has been proved wrong.

Comment: While the bullet points listed are true, ENUM is still faster than JOINS, especially if you are ordering by that column.  For columns like gender with set values that don't change, I prefer using ENUM.  If there is even a remote possibility that you will need to add or remove values though, go with a JOIN or use a CHAR/VARCHAR/TINYINT and manage them on the application level.  One other thing...MySQL doesn't store the actual value in the column, only an index (INT), so you might as well use the full text string to display to your users (ie Male instead of M) and save additional coding. ;-)

Comment: @Jabari, true, but you can use a foreign key to a natural key in the lookup table (that is, no auto-increment), and then you don't need to do a join.

Comment: @Bill Very true, but why do so if you have a few values that will never change?  I like to keep my databases & queries as lean as possible.  Creating a whole new table to hold "Male", "Female", and "Unknown" is untidy (for lack of a better word).  If it increases performance or the values may change at some point, then by all means create another table!  Otherwise it's just bloat.

Comment: @Jabari, that's your aesthetic opinion.  I could just as easily say it's untidy to declare columns as ENUM, so I can't query the list of permitted values.

Comment: @Bill - I know this is a late reply!  Why would you do a query for something like Male/Female/Unknown?  As I stated above, this should only be used in cases where you know for a fact (I'm talking 100% positive) that the values are set and will never change.  Therefore, querying for something you already know would be bad programming.  Also, it's not just for aesthetics.  The performance will be better that way than with a join.  Performance is a measurable, so it's far from being an opinion...aesthetic or otherwise.

Comment: @Jabari, yes, I agree using an ENUM is okay if you have a set that really never changes.  Then you can hard-code the set of values in your app so you don't need to query that set from the database.  But in cases where the set of values might change, hard-coding them in the app creates a risk that the set will change in the db and no one will remember to re-code the app.  There are no solutions without some kind of downside.  It's up to you to judge which risk is acceptable for a given app.

Answer (score 30):

ENUMs are represented internally by 1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of values. If the strings you're storing are larger than 2 bytes and rarely change, then an ENUM is the way to go. Comparison will be faster with an enum and they take up less space on disk, which in turn can lead to faster seek times.

The downside is that enums are less flexible when it comes to adding/removing values.

Comment: I am not sure which version of MySQL you were referring to. But since 5.0, the size of enum type is either 1 or 2 bytes depends on number of possible values according to the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html Since there are only 5 to 10 possible values, the size should be 1 byte

Comment: @Lacek You're right! I'll change the answer from 16-bits to 1 or 2 bytes

Answer (score 13):

In this article [Using the ENUM data type to increase performance](http://fernandoipar.com/2009/03/09/using-the-enum-data-type-to-increase-performance/) Fernando looks into performances of Enum type for queries.

The result is that while using ENUM might seem a little less elegant from a design point of view  (if your ENUM value are changing sometimes), the performance gain is obvious for large datasets.

> Well, it's quite obvious that while using ENUM might seem a little less elegant from a design point of view (what happens if I use Types in more than just one table? What if I want to add a type? I have to alter the table!), the performance benefits, if I'm going to be handling large quantities of data (and my tests have been with small amounts, but I don't have a server, just a very humble notebook) might be worthwhile.

See his article for details. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

No, see a comparison [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/)

The advantage lays in code readability.

Comment: According to the article you linked there IS a performance advantage to using ENUM as long as you are not altering possible states.