# Enum in Hibernate, persisting as an enum

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, enums

In my MySQL database, there's the column "gender enum('male','female')"

I've created my enum "com.mydomain.myapp.enums.Gender", and in my `Person` entity I'm defined "Gender gender".

Now I'd want to keep the enum type in my MySQL database, but when I launch my application I get:

> Wrong column type in MyApp.Person for column Gender. Found: enum, expected: integer

Why is this? This would be the equivalent as if I'd annotated my "Gender gender" with "@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)", which I haven't. EnumType seems only to be able to be either ORDINAL or STRING, so how do I specify that it should treat the field as an enum, not as an int? (not that there's much difference, but enough for it to get upset about it.)

Comment: sending integers shud work. male = 1 , female = 2

Comment: Using Hibernate, how would you suggest I annotate my Entity class to do that? I've tried defining my enum values explicitly "public enum Gender ( MALE(1), FEMALE(2); }" with no difference in error output

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My understanding is that MySQL enum type is very proprietary and not well supported by Hibernate, see [this comment](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBSEAM-637?focusedCommentId=12349681#action_12349681) from Gavin King (this related issue is a bit different but that's not the important part).

So, I actually think that you'll have to use your own `UsereType` and I'd recommend to use the **Flexible solution - working version** from the [Java 5 EnumUserType](https://www.hibernate.org/272.html) (see Appfuse's [Java 5 Enums Persistence with Hibernate](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Java+5+Enums+Persistence+with+Hibernate) for an example).

Personally, I'd just forget the idea to use MySQL enum, I'm not convinced that the "benefits" are worth it (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766299/mysql-enum-performance-advantage) for more details).

Answer (score 32):

If you give Hibernate a column definition, it won't try to guess one:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "enum('MALE','FEMALE')")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender;
```

If you aren't relying on Hibernate to generate your schema for any reason, you don't even have to provide real values for the columnDefinition. This way, you remove an instance where you need to keep the values in sync.  Just keep your Java enum and your Liquibase or SQL script in sync:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "enum('DUMMY')")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ManyValuedEnum manyValuedEnum;
```

Answer (score 19):

Try to use @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) and define your enum like this

```
enum Gender {
  male,
  female
}
```

Note lower case values.

This will work at least with VARCHAR columns. It will store enum as string 'male' or 'female'.

Comment: As written, I'm using enum type column, not varchar

Comment: Have you actually tried my suggestion? gender type in mysql is probably just some wrapping/syntactic sugar around a varchar or char column.

Answer (score 5):

not sure why it is not in Hibernate documentation
but you can do this

```
<property name="type" column="type" not-null="true">
    <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
        <param name="enumClass">com.a.b.MyEnum</param>
        <param name="type">12</param>
        <!-- 12 is java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
    </type> 
</property>
```

Comment: Thx, this works fine with a MySQL ENUM column, though 12 is for VARCHAR

Comment: How to do this with annotations?

Answer (score 4):

Not for this case but if someone is using XML mapping:

```
<property name="state" column="state" not-null="true">
  <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
    <param name="enumClass">com.myorg.persistence.data.State</param>
  </type>
</property>
```

The database column type must be numeric e.g. tinyint on a mysql to make reading ordinal values possible.