# Can I configure Play to use mysql enums instead of ints?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

My model contains an enum, which are mapped by JPA to an `int` column on my mysql database.

mysql has a native `enum` type, that would be more convenient to use.

How can I configure JPA to use this type?

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
  public enum Role {
    User,
    Moderator,
    Admin,
  }

  public Role role;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160700/enum-in-hibernate-persisting-as-an-enum     and in short: DO NOT USE MYSQL ENUM! There are nicer patterns, using ORDINAL for compactness and STRING for readability. You can make an enum with a short string for the database, and a longer one for your code.

Comment: @Stefano - not really a duplicate because of the context of Play Framework. But anyway, I didn't really know whether enum is proprietary mysql or not. I wouldn't want to change my code just to support a proprietary mysql behavior, so I probably will be sticking to Play defaults.

Comment: looks like i'm reading all of your play! questions now :D ; I would say in this case it does not make any difference whether you're going through Play! or not, because Play! just extends JPA/Hibernate so every problem there will be an issue with Play! too!

Comment: @Stefano - I tend to ask a lot of questions (that's how I got most of my Stack Overflow rep). I accepted the answer, not sure if it's an _exact_ dup or not, because of the context that I intended (even if they turned out to have the same answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built in support for enum AFAIK, but maybe you can try this as workaround (I never test it thought):

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    public enum Role {
        User,
        Moderator,
        Admin,
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('User', 'Moderator', 'Admin')")
    public Role role;
}
```

You can use [EnumType.STRING](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EnumType.html) which will store the value as String in the database.
But using native ENUM require you to define the columnDefinition using [@Column](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) annotation which need all your roles to be harcoded there, you see? duplication here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out when I get a chance.

Comment: @ripper234 which means it's quite a bad idea :) !