# Unable to Generate enum type in MySql from JPA entity

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, java-ee-7

I am using JPA 2.1. I want to genrate mysql enum type column like: `gender enum('male','female')`. My Enum class is

```
public enum Gender {
  MALE,
  FEMALE
}
```

In JPA entity class

```
@Enumerated
private Gender gender;//generate int type column
```

And

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender; //generate varchar type column.
```

Is there any way to generate enum type column in MySql?

Comment: You might want to give this a try - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8710305/738746

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use following code:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE;
}

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('User', 'Moderator', 'Admin')")
public Role role;
}
```

Comment: Not only does this not compile, but also it mixes up `Gender` and `Role` and therefore doesn't answer the question, nor explain anything. Why would people upvote this?

Comment: While the example is put together negligently, this is the only answer I was able to find that shows how to map an enum to an actual SQL ENUM type with JPA, as opposed to just storing your enum values in an unsafe number or string type.

Comment: Is enum type ANSI compatible? Is enum defined in standard SQL or it's just for MySQL? In that case: isn't this solution coupling the `@Entity` class (I asume `Person` or something alike) with the DB table (and the DBMS)?

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to use string enumeration value in database, the column type must be `varchar` base on database sever. Actually, I am not clear `I want to genrate mysql enum type column`. But, if u would like to display the output `MALE` to `male`, reference as below :

```
public enum Gender {
    FEMALE("female"), MALE("male");

    private String label;

    private Gender(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

test calss

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(Gender.MALE)
}
```

Output : male