# How to set an entity with enum column with default property value in SpringBoot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, enums, entity

I am using `Springboot 2.7.2`with `Hibernate` and `Mysql 8`. Is there a way to make an `Entity` class so as to execute a create table Query like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
    `SettingsId` enum('1') NOT NULL,
    ................,
    ................,
     PRIMARY KEY (`SettingsId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710305/13660072) and made the Entity Class like this

```
@Entity
public class Settings {
    public enum SettingsId {
    }

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('1')")
    private SettingsId settingsId;

    ........;
    ........;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

1. add @EnableAutoConfiguration
2. add application.properties. like below :

   - spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
   - spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

Comment: Please note that `Mysql` `data type` is `enum`.

Comment: Oh I missed it.

@Column(columnDefinition = "ENUM('1', ... , '10' )") will be do that