# SQL insert with enums?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, enums

how can I insert SQL value for eg:

```
class MyEnum {
    FOO, BAR
}
```

which is later mapped to a `MyEnum property = MyEnum.FOO`;

How can I 
`INSERT into XX (property) values ('FOO')`?

When I try it like this, I get:

```
Data conversion error converting "'FOO' (MYENUM INTEGER)";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160700/enum-in-hibernate-persisting-as-an-enum does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to map java enum to hibernate. [this](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Java+5+Enums+Persistence+with+Hibernate) and [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Java5EnumUserType) might help.

Answer (score 0):

you got to convert your enum into a hibernate user type and change the mapping of the column to the `UserType` class. take a look at this [Reference](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeForPersistingAnEnumWithAVARCHARColumn)