# Trouble deciding on field type in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I want to create a table of vehicles which stores:

- Vehicle id
- Vehicle name
- Vehicle stock
- Vehicle condition

Vehicle condition can be "new" or "used".

I do not want to store this field as a String, and I want to avoid making it a Boolean because I would have to make it either is_new or is_old and this approach does not feel satisfying.

Edit: Enum appears to be the ideal solution, however I would still like to know how I would go around adding new conditions if it becomes necessary.

Is there a more expressive way of storing vehicle condition, or will I have to settle for String or Boolean?

Thanks!

Comment: If you envision more conditions (like "slightly used" or "almost new") you can put them in a separate table and link it to your main one (through PK/FK).

Comment: Why do you not want to store it as a string?

Comment: Depending on the size and life expectancy of your table, you may want to put `Vehicle Name` (is it something like Model and Make?) into a separate table as well.

Comment: @Mike Sherill 'Catcall' I want the database to reject accidental invalid entries such as "Usex".

Comment: @PM77-1 It's meant to be a simple table for my Database Management Systems course, I am still deciding how to organize it, but there is no information given on what kind of cars I store, so I imagine that I can identify cars fairly easily simply by their name.

Comment: @Dmitry: Rejecting invalid data has nothing to do with strings. Nothing at all. You could use either foreign keys or CHECK() constraints to reject invalid data.

Comment: CHECK() does indeed solve the problem as well, but I would prefer to avoid checks in this particular project. Although I can imagine it being a more correct solution. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an `ENUM('USED', 'NEW)`. This defines the different types the value can be, so it's either one or the other, like a boolean, but more expressive.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! If it was helpful, I would appreciate marking it as "Best Answer"

Comment: 11 minutes until I can do so.

Comment: @mattpic This is **not** the right approach. `enum` has a [performance penalty](http://stackoverflow.com/a/766345/679449). For 2 options, a `boolean` type is the correct solution.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with ENUM in SQL. Google "why not to use enum in sql" for many references.

Comment: @mattpic I advise you against marking ANY answer as correct within the first 24 hours. Wait until the community gave you multiple option, then tomorrow pick the best one that fits you: it's counterproductive if you accept it too soon.

Comment: I am still wondering how to make it so I can add new conditions. Boolean is sufficient for this case, but in case I will get 3 or 4 conditions, I can no longer store it as a Boolean. I can do a String, but this is subject to invalid entries, the same problem with associating it with a particular table of conditions.

Comment: @STT LCU I can always change the accepted answer. matt has gave me the solution I needed.

Comment: @Dmitry Did you not read the answer I provided? The **correct** solution is to create a table for your conditions.

Comment: @Dmitry the community isn't encouraged to answer a question with an accepted answer. whatever.

Comment: Only there are no ENUM (or BOOLEAN, for that matter) column types in DB2...

Comment: @mustaccio Apparently this magically answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

If new and used are the only two fields, then you could opt for a boolean field. If there was ever a third option, then you should create a table of vehicle condition options. You should also avoid using a column type of `enum`. There is a [performance penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766345/679449). The correct approach would be to use a look up table if you have more than 2 options.

Comment: I agree about Enums being problematic in MySQL (as your link explains.) But this question is tagged with "DB2" and I'm not sure if DB2 has enums to start with!

Comment: Also I agree with the lookup table solution (with a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.)