# MySQL ENUM VS INT

Tags: php, mysql

I have few tables that have columns that can either be `ENUM` type or `INT` type. I tend to always use integer type assuming that it will be faster to perform search based on it.

For example one of my table has a column: `StatusType` which can have only 4 possible values: `Completed`, `In Progress`, `Failed`, `Todo`.

Instead of storing above as `ENUM` strings I store them as:

`1`, `2`, `3`, `4` respectively. And then in my PHP code I have constant variables that define these values like this:

```
define('COMPLETED', 1);
define('IN_PROGRESS', 2);
define('FAILED', 3);
define('TODO', 4);
```

Now my question is, am I doing it right way or I should just change it to be `ENUM` type and use strings to compare in queries? I have many other columns that can only have set of max `4-5` possible values.

Comment: why not store them as strings in an varchar column then?

Comment: @karlingen search is faster on integer than on string isnt it ?

Comment: How are you using the table? Is it most written to or mostly read from?

Comment: @JNevill mostly read. But its also written alot.

Comment: Use php enums: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php, read other answers to know why.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Enum values look really cool in MySQL, yet I am not a fan of them. They are limited to 255 values, so if you decide to add more values, then you might run into a limit. Also, as you describe, you need to synchronize the values in your application code with the values in the database -- something that seems potentially dangerous.

In addition, they make certain future changes more difficult. For instance, other databases do not support enums. And, if you want to add multi-lingual support, having codes embedded in data type definitions in the database is a bit hard to deal with.

The more standard method is one or more reference tables, where you use `join` to get the values. You can use a hybrid approach where you use a reference table in the database. Then you can *load* the reference table into the application to get the mapping from numbers to strings so you can avoid the joins in your code.

Comment: so basically have another table called `Statuses` and have `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID that is primary key & also reference to the `StatusType` table? Also `Statuses` will have a string to represent which status it is. Now this sounds like a good solution but say I wanted to select `All Completed` records. I would still need to compare to a string in reference table right?

Comment: I was writing this same thing. Store your StatusType_Code/StatusType_Desc in a separate table. Use the code in big tables and only call the separate text table when you need the text values.

Comment: @GGio - In fact, whether to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` or not is actually not relevant to the subject (though I'd advice against it since the value set does not seem particularly dynamic).

Comment: Also on the Auto_Increment, you might find that you want to number your text/descriptions in a certain way in the future. You might find it valuable to number then as 10,20,30,40 in case you want to sort in the future and add new values into the sort without renumbering everything. AutoIncrement is nice, but overkill here and possibly restrictive.

Answer (score 6):

You are half-correct.  Enum is very bad from a performance perspective: [MySQL Enum performance advantage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766299/mysql-enum-performance-advantage)

That said, binding the definitions of the `INT`s to your code is also not a great thing.  Ideally, if you were to follow the correct Data Normalization patterns, you would define the values of the `INT`s in the Database as well, in another table, and use the index of the definition as the value for the assignment.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

The reason for this is so the data is portable, and useful without requiring the Codebase to read it (you can easily dump a CSV for Excel by executing a join).

God Speed.

Example SQL:

```
SELECT *, state.name AS state FROM students
JOIN states ON student.state_id = states.id
```

Just to get state names.

Or to filter:

```
SELECT * FROM students
JOIN states ON student.state_id = states.id
WHERE state.name = 'Maine' OR state.code = 'ME'
```

Yeah, strange example, but the idea is that `INT`s are TINY, and `VARCHAR` are...  variable...  Storing 'Maine' as opposed to '16' adds up over millions of rows.  Further, the indexing on `INT` is MUCH faster than `VARCHAR`, so your look-ups are going to be much faster.  Particularly if you inherently know the number ahead of time and build your query without the `JOIN`.  This is not advisable as a common practice, but could be done if you wanted to make something even faster and you can ensure the validity of the assumed value.

Comment: so say I wanted to select all `Completed` records. I would have something like this: `SELECT * FROM StatusType INNER JOIN Statuses ON SsID = StID WHERE SsName = 'Completed'` this still compares to the string doesnt it ? SsName would be the column in the reference table

Comment: @GGio, Yes this will compare on the string, but the table in which it is comparing is only 4 or 5 records. It will then join back to your big table using the ID, so your read on your big table is still speedy. Any loss of speed here is just due to the JOIN. Consider rewriting your example SQL statement to use the ID in the where so you can avoid the join. Only reach out to the key/value table when you actually need to bring the value into your front end for a user to see.