# Enum types in database schema

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

This might be sort of a basic db question, but I'm more used to working with objects rather than tables. Let's say I have an object 'Movie' with property 'genre'. Genre should be restricted by using enumerated types (eg. the only valid genres are Horror, Action, Comedy, Drama). How should this translate to a db schema?

- I could put a 'genre' column in the Movies table and rely on checking inputs to ensure that a 'genre' assignment is valid?
- Or, I could include a Genres table with pre-filled rows, and then in the Movies table include a column with a foreign key to the Genres table?

I'm leaning towards the first option, but are there pitfalls/etc. that I'm not considering?

Answer (score 2):

I lean toward using the lookup table, your second option. The reason I prefer this is that I can add a new genre simply by adding a row to the Genres table. There would be no need to modify code or to modify the enum definition in the schema.

See also my answer to [How to handle enumerations without enum fields in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761211/how-to-handle-enumerations-without-enum-fields-in-a-database/761343#761343)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful heuristic: Do you treat all values the same from the client code?

- If you do, then just use the lookup table. Even if you don't envision adding new values<sup>1</sup> now, requirements tend to change as the time marches on, and the lookup table will allow you to do that without changing the client code. Your case seems to fall into that category.
- If you don't, then enum is likely more appropriate - the "knowledge" about each distinct value is contained in your client code anyway, so there is nothing useful left to store in the database.

The gray zone is if you do a little bit of both. E.g. you need to treat values in special ways, but there is still some additional field (associated to each value) that you can treat generically (e.g. just display it to the user). Or you need to treat just *some* values in special ways. In cases like these, I'd lean towards the lookup table.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Or deleting or modifying old values.*