# Proper solution for storing only few values - column or table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got a huge table 'books' storing book information where I plan to have a row for media type, let's call it 'media_ID'. I know that I'm dealing here with only three possible values: book, ebook and audiobook.

So, making a separate table out of this three values seems to me like wasting especially when I have to include it in every query which feels also unnecessary to me. So what's a clean solution for such cases? Maybe using a PHP array in a config file? What are you using?

```
books
-------
ID
media_ID
title
...

medias
-------
ID
type
```

MySQL data:

```
CREATE `books` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `media_ID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `title` tinytext NOT NULL,
  )

INSERT INTO `books` (`ID`, `media_ID`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Some print book title'),
(2, 1, 'Other print book title'),
(3, 2, 'First ebook title'),
(4, 2, 'Second ebook title'),
(5, 3, 'Single audio book title');

CREATE TABLE `medias` (
  `ID` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `medias` (`ID`, `Medium`) VALUES
(1, 'book'),
(2, 'ebook'),
(3, 'audiobook');
```

Or just php array:

```
$medias = array("book", "ebook", "audiobook");
```

Comment: Using a table will make it easier to add more types in the future, you won't have to find every PHP script and update the array.

Comment: So a book can never be available simultaneously as an ebook and an audiobook, say?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Where do you see a comma-separated value in any column?

Comment: @Barmar my bad I misinterpreted `Maybe using php Array in a config file?`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty He's using that array to translate the numeric `mediaID` values to strings, e.g. `$medias[$row['media_ID']]`

Comment: @Barmar To be fair, within the question title itself, there is an implication along these lines

Comment: @Strawberry So he writes a clear question, including a code example that shows what he's talking about, and you're going by a poorly worded title?

Comment: @Strawberry: I can see how confusion is caused by the title. Wouldja amend?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. Sorry if my title confused someone - I'm not a native speaker so my ability to speak out my thoughts are limited by language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd use a [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) for this.

```
    `mediaType` ENUM('book', 'ebook', 'audiobook') not null
```

Comment: I totally forgot about the enum data type - the production blindness is here ;( So thanks for remembering me about it's existence. This is exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 4):

Using a separate table for just 3 values is NOT out of the ordinary.
Furthermore this will give you the option of adding more attributes in the future-if the need arises...something that will be an issue with ENUM column type.
In my app...I have such a table that stores the payments packages the user selected...and these are only three. 
So go for a table **if you are not sure about your future needs/requirements**.

Comment: You can always edit an enum column and add / remove values if the requirements change though, just as easily as it is to create the new row.

Comment: +1 for this answer, I totally agree. Here's a great article that describes why it's usually better to go for a separate table rather than an enum column: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: I agree with @Harlan that editing an `enum` is fine. However, if you re-order the strings in the definition, I wonder if MySQL internally re-writes existing values?

Comment: editing an enum can become "expensive"...it is better to be avoided

Comment: Thank you Dimitiris to pointing out the enum cons. Actually I'm searching for the lightest possible solution because my books table already has tons of necessary foreign keys so I try to avoid new ones. You're right with the flexibility but I will go for the enum.
@deniz Good article. Thank you for sharing it.

Comment: I liked this approach!

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use lookup tables to handle enumaration. Just found the solution here: [How to handle enumerations without enum fields in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761211/how-to-handle-enumerations-without-enum-fields-in-a-database/761343#761343).

```
CREATE `books` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `media` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `title` tinytext NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (media) REFERENCES medias(Medium)
  )
```