# Best way of saving object and it's type in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, oop, database-design, relational-database

Using an object oriented programming language I'm in situation where I have an Object where one of the properties is the type of the object. When I save it to the database I always create two tables, one for the object itself and the other one for the object type (id, name). Then I assign the typeId to the object and create a Foreign Key to ObjectType table. I'm not sure that this is correct because:

- I'm using a whole table to save only few records (5-10 possible Object types) and they will be rarely updated.
- I need to do a JOIN between two tables to show the name of the object type.
- In the code I'm declaring constants with the same ID as in the type table (to operate when programming and assigning the type to object) and I don't like this redundancy.

The other option is to use a string and save it directly in the object´s table but this doesn't sound good because the search will be slower than with typeId and there is no list about all the possible types. Also changing the name of one type is more complicated. Can you advice me what is the best thing to do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you have 3 options:

1. Varchar
2. Enum Fields
3. an other Joined table (Lookup table).

And you have 5 evaluation parameters:

1. Redundancy
2. Extendability
3. Modifiability
4. Performance
5. Simplicity

**Varchar**:

1. Very Bad (you should copy the values)
2. Good (you can add new types easily)
3. Very Bad (you should change all inserted data with the same value)
4. Excellent (based on reference)
5. Excellent (easy to use as other fields and in ORMs)

**Enum Fields:**

1. Good (DBMS control the redundancy)
2. Very Very Bad (based on reference)
3. Very Very Bad (based on reference)
4. Excellent (based on reference)
5. Very Good (some ORMs behave as String Field-see [this reference](https://www.brandonsavage.net/why-you-should-replace-enum-with-something-else/))

**an other Joined table (Lookup Table)**:

1. Excellent (ER normal method)
2. Excellent (ER normal method)
3. Excellent (ER normal method)
4. Normal (maybe bad - if the speed is so important)
5. Normal (depend on programmer)

**References**:

see Performance analysis here ([Enum Fields VS Varchar VS Int + Joined table: What is Faster?](https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/)).

see Enum advantages and disadvantages here ([8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)).

see Lookup table and Varchar example in mysql [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761211/how-to-handle-enumerations-without-enum-fields-in-a-database/761343#761343) in SO.

**Finally**: based on your evaluation parameters, you can choose the proper option.

The other possibility is to use just an Integer number in Database and manage all things in source code. I do not put it in evaluation because it is not database design. It is programming approach.